# How to install an other apk from same project when installing app?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a multi-module project with 2 applications.
For one of the applications, I would like to install the other apk as well on every install (so basically I don't have to do it myself every time).
Is this possible with Gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have the following project structure:

```
root/
    app1/
    app2/
    build.gralde
    settings.gradle
    gradlew
    gradlew.bat
    // ...
```

To install *app1* using Gradle you can specify for which sub-project you would like execute certain task:

```
./gradlew :app1:installDebug
```

The same with *app2*:

```
./gradlew :app2:installDebug
```

To install both applications on your device, execute:

```
./gradlew installDebug
```

It will execute `installDebug` task for each sub-project.